# The input data is not a complete block

Tags: c#, encryption-symmetric

[image][image]Scenario: One symmetric key, each user has his own IV, the documents are stored in a NVARCHAR(MAX) field. When I try to to decrypt the file, I get:
**The input data is not a complete block.**

```
// Create symmetric key
public static byte[] CreateKey()
{
    AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCrypto = (AesCryptoServiceProvider)AesCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
    byte[] key = aesCrypto.Key;
    return key;
}

//Get key (stored in a database)
public static Byte[] GetAppKey()
{
    return db.Encryptors.Where(x => x.EncryptorID == 1).Single().EncryptionKey.ToArray();
}

// Get application IV (stored in database)
public static Byte[] GetAppIV()
{
    return db.Encryptors.Where(x => x.EncryptorID == 1).Single().IV.ToArray();
}

// Encrypt document (this will be stored in a VARBINARY(MAX) field
public static byte[] EncryptBinaryToBytes(Binary document, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] key = GetAppKey();
    byte[] encrypted;

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCsp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aesCsp.Key = key;
        aesCsp.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesCsp.CreateEncryptor(aesCsp.Key, aesCsp.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    swEncrypt.Write(document);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    // return the encrypted document
    return encrypted;
}

// Decrypt document
public static byte[] DecryptBytesToBytes(byte[] document, byte[] iv) 
{
    byte[] key = GetAppKey();

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCsp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aesCsp.Key = key;
        aesCsp.IV = iv;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesCsp.CreateDecryptor(aesCsp.Key, aesCsp.IV);

        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swDecrypt = new StreamWriter(csDecrypt))
                {
                    swDecrypt.Write(document);
                }
                byte[] decrypted = msDecrypt.ToArray();
                // return the unencrypted document
                return decrypted;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

To store the document

```
    byte[] fileByte = fluUploadFile.FileBytes;
    Binary document = new Binary(fileByte);

    byte[] appIv = AES.GetAppIV();
    byte[] encryptedDocument = AES.EncryptBinaryToBytes(document, appIv);
    byte[] decryptedDocument = AES.DecryptBytesToBytes(encryptedDocument, appIv);
    Document d = new Document()
    {
        OriginalName = originalName,
        DocSize = fileSize,
        BinaryDocument = encryptedDocument,
        UploadedName = uploadedFileName,
        MimeType = MIMEType,
        DocExtension = extension
    };
    db.Documents.InsertOnSubmit(d);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: How do you store your binary data in the text filed and converted it back again? I would just use varbinary and be done with it.

Comment: Is the NVARCHAR padding your bytes?

Comment: I added the comment to show how the file is loaded into the database.

Answer (score 2):

It's really important that you change the data type of the database field to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, that way you avoid issues with character encodings and byte combinations that cannot be interpreted as legal characters.

Also, I think the problem is that you are not closing the streams before calling `ToArray()` method on the `MemoryStream` in both encrypt and decrypt routines. It's very important to call `Close()` in the `CryptoStream` so that `FlushFinalBlock()` is called and the encryption process writes the final block to the stream.

Try moving the call to `MemoryStream.ToArray()` to the outer `using` block, that is, outside the `using` block of `CryptoStream`, so that `Dispose()` is called on the `CryptoStream` and call `MemoryStream.Close()` before that.

Another problem with your code is that you are wrapping the `CryptoStream` with a `StreamWriter`, which writes the *text* representation of the object you pass into the `Write` method.  You should instead write directly to the `CryptoStream` to avoid any byte to string conversions.

Comment: XintO, I pasted your code and the encryption works with the old and new code. The decryption, however, does not work with neither the code I posted nor your revised code.